# How to unit test dependant cpde

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have some code that looks like this:

```
public class A()
{
    public string property1 {get; private set;}
    public string property2 {get; private set;}

    public B property3 {get; private set;}

    public A(string json)
    {
        ReadProperty1(json);
        ReadProperty2(json);
        ReadProperty3(json);
    }

    void ReadProperty1(string json){...}
    void ReadProperty2(string json){...}
    void ReadProperty3(string json){...}
}

public class B()
{
    public string property1 {get; private set;}
    public string property2 {get; private set;}

    public B(string json)
    {
        //Read properties 1 and 2...
    }
}
```

I can unit test the creation of class 'B' in isolation just fine, but I can't come up with a solution to unit test class 'A' in isolation.

In order for the code to work, the json passed to 'A' HAS TO contain a property that can be parsed into an object of type 'B', properly formatted; so when I try to unit test 'A', the input json needs to have the data of not only 'A' (that is, properties 1 and 2 of 'A'), but also of 'B'. That, for me, looks a little bit weird since doing that would also be testing clas 'B' in the unit test of 'A'...

The thing is that 'A' needs property3 (the one of type 'B') properly set in order to work, so I cannot construct 'A' without 'B'.

This may not look much of a problem, but it gets worse when the chain extends to class 'C' and 'D' etc.

It it more or less the same problem as if you needed to unit test a whole car. You can unit test its parts, like the engine, the wheels etc. But in order to unit test the car itself you need to have a valid engine and valid wheels.

I think I'm kind of missing the point somewhere and doing something wrong and I just can't figure it out.

Would anyone be so kind as to enlighten me on how to properly unit test this kind of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with some serious refactoring of my code here.

1. I would take all the serialization/deserialization code outside of the class scope. This way you can unit test the serialization/deserialization properly and have a generic mechanism for this. Create an `Interface` like `IMySerializer` and inject into the class A. This way you can mock using something like `Moq` and control the returing values.
2. Fake the Property B. Whatever you do with Property B, should be 100% expected. If property C under B changes behavior, then Class `A` should still execute properly the Unit tests. Only Class `C` should fail in their unit tests.
3. If you are testing the serialization of the entire car, then there is no way around it. You need to provide the entire string. With all the sub-properties. Is there really a reason to do this though?

Expanding on three. Let's say you have a Car. It has Brakes and Accelerator properties. You can Moq both classes and simulate the functionality of the Car to always have the expected values. When `Accelerator.Push()` occurs, then some new values is returned. This value should be controlled. With the controlled value of `Brakes.Push()` and the previous one, the car should unit test the current speed. That speed is what should be unit tested.

Comment: I understand the answer. However, creating a deserializer for class A would still require the data to hold appropiate data to be deserialized into class B. And I am not sure about the mocking process, since I can't inject B into A because it is class A that creates its own class B object.

I am still not really sure how to proceed.